# Sonicwall TZ300 - Verifying and increasing Max Wireless Clients for non virtual AP

Tags: sonicwall

Device: Dell Sonicwall TZ300w

Firmware: SonicOS Enhanced 6.2.4.2-20n

I am not utilizing any Virtual Access Points, so I am only using one SSID.

The way I setup the wifi is essentially the way the wizard sets it up.

1. Login
2. Configure SSID/wireless settings in: "Wireless > Settings and Wireless > Security"

If I go to "Wireless > Advanced", Maximum Client Associations is set to 128. What I am not clear on, is if this is the maximum amount of clients per the physical sonicwall wireless device or for the SSID I created in the steps above.

The confusion comes when I go to "Wireless > Virtual Access Points. I see the SSID I created above. However for Max clients it says 16. I understand that 16 is the default max client size for the sonicwall.

All the instructions that I find are about increasing the max amount of clients if I were to setup additional virtual access points which appear easy and straight forward. However, I have been unsuccessful on finding any information on how to verify or increase the max amount of clients if I am not deploying any additional SSIDs. All I need is one SSID.

How do I confirm if the max amount of clients for my single SSID is 16 or 128?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to clarify with a Dell tech.

1. Wireless > Advanced" = The overall allowed clients for the device.
2. Wireless > Virtual Access Points. = shows the allowed amount of clients per SSID. However it is recommended to use Internet Explorer, as I was using chrome and that is why the setting values weren't displaying properly for me. They only recommend Internet Explorer for viewing the sonicwall admin.